# ¿Cómo podría llevar esta función de php a mysql con una función o procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: php, mysql, function

estoy intentando llevar una funcionalidad que hago en php a mysql mediante una función o procedimiento almacenado, aunque me gustaría más si fuera una función.

Me gustaría que la función de mysql me devolviera la fecha mínima que tuviera para id_av.

Este es el trozo de código que me gustaría llevar a php:

```
<?php
// my controler
function toFunctionMySQL()
{
    $date = array();
    $listIdAv =  $this->mi_model->getListIdAv();
    foreach ($listIdAv as $av) {
        
        $dateFirstChangeStatus = $this->mi_model->getDateFirstChangeStatusForIdAv($av);
        array_push($date, $dateFirstChangeStatus);
    }
}

// my model
function getDateFirstChangeStatusForIdAv( $idAv)
{
    return $this->db->query(" SELECT DATE_FORMAT( MIN(date_change) , '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s' ) AS date_change FROM `av` WHERE change_status LIKE 'change status%' AND id_av = $idAv ")->row()->date_change;

}

function getListIdAv()
{
    return $this->db->query("SELECT id_av from av")->result_array();
}

?>
```

Hasta ahora lo que he hecho ha sido la siguiente función, pero me está retornando una misma fecha, según pensaba, que si hago una llamada a una función, y a esta le paso como parametro un campo de una tabla, haciendo select mifuncion(id_av) from av; me muestra la misma fecha para todos los registros.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `mifunction`(id_av int) RETURNS varchar(25) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN

declare dateText VARCHAR(25);

SELECT DATE_FORMAT( MIN(date_change) , '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s' ) 
into dateText 
FROM `av` 
WHERE change_status LIKE 'change status%' AND id_av = id_av ;
if dateText is null then 
    set dateText = '';
end if;
RETURN dateText;
END
```

¿ Alguna forma de llevar ese trozo de código de php a mysql con una función ?

Los registros que me arroja la query del model

SELECT DATE_FORMAT( MIN(date_change) , '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s' )
FROM `av`
WHERE date_change LIKE 'change status%' AND id_av = 223 ;

me retorna la fecha mínima según el id_av, en este caso

> '05-04-2021 20:38:01'

para el id_av 223

con la función me retorna varias registros pero con la misma fecha.

```
select mifunction(id_av) from av;
```

> 31-03-2021 11:17:15 31-03-2021 11:17:15 31-03-2021 11:17:15 31-03-2021
> 11:17:15 31-03-2021 11:17:15

Comment: Buenas, Roberto, ¿puedes aportar un mínimo juego de datos indicando qué te devuelve la consulta lanzada desde PHP y qué te devuelve la función?  Aparte, he visto que has estado editando y cambiando los nombres de las columnas al inglés. Al final te ha quedado diferente la consulta en PHP que la de la función, échale un ojo.

Comment: Despues de corregidas algunas cosas, ¿la columna con la fecha y la columna que contiene el texto 'change status%' no deberían ser diferentes? Una de tipo fecha y otra de tipo texto. Ahí arriba aparecen ambas como date_change, ¿eso es correcto?

Comment: @RubioRic muchas gracias por comentar, disculpa no me fijé bien en la query.

Answer (score 1):

He intentado reproducir tu función y creo que el error está en la consulta que declaras en la función, más concretamente

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MIN(date_change) , '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') 
into dateText 
FROM `av` 
WHERE change_status LIKE 'change status%' AND id_av = id_av;
```

Si te fijas estás poniendo al final

```
id_av = id_av
```

Lo cual es siempre TRUE, con lo cual tu consulta es equivalente a

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MIN(date_change) , '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') 
into dateText 
FROM `av` 
WHERE change_status LIKE 'change status%';
```

Es decir la fecha mínima de toda la tabla AV con el status 'change status%'.

Ejecuta esta consulta

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MIN(date_change) , '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') 
FROM `av` 
WHERE change_status LIKE 'change status%';
```

y seguramente obtengas `31-03-2021 11:17:15`

Si reemplazas el nombre del argumento de tu función por uno que no colisione con los nombres de las columnas, obtendrás el resultado esperado. Yo he definido la función así

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `MI_FUNCION`(searchId INT) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8mb4
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE dateText TEXT;

    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MIN(date_change), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s' ) into dateText 
    FROM AV 
    WHERE status LIKE 'change status%' AND id_av = searchId;
    
    IF dateText is null THEN 
        SET dateText = '';
    END IF;

    RETURN dateText;
END
```

Cambiando el nombre del argumento de id_av a searchId y funciona correctamente. No te enlazo un sqlfiddle porque no funciona muy bien con las declaraciones de funciones.

Comment: muchas gracias por responder y por tu tiempo. Era esa chorrada fack.

Comment: @RobertoAlonsoPepónSanchez De nada :-)